# Random Field Entries

Tags: random

I am working on a site for a client who posts many jobs for chefs.

A lot of the jobs are essentially similar, so writing the job postings is something I am trying to simplify.

I can write a series of statements that will serve up similar job descriptions, with pre-written statements that then use |replace to integrate other field data.

So an example statement:

We cook %jobFoodType% to %jobRatingStars%.

Would render as:

'We cook Pub food to a 3 star rating.'

I can write many of these type of statements which can either be selected from a drop down, but I'd like to go a step further and have the drop down when entering a new entry, to be randomly selected from the list of options.

So what I'm asking for, is there a way Craft can randomly pre-populate a field, with a set of predefined statements.

I've had a look at Randomm plugin, which while useful, doesn't let me pre-populate from a predefined set of statements like sentences.

The alternative is to use Randomm to create a random number I use to pick a statement that is in the template, but for obvious reasons, I'd prefer the statements to be driven from Craft.

Any help / thoughts much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused... you're putting a heavy emphasis on this being a _random_ process, but it seems like you're trying to generate very _specific_ results. What exactly is "random" about it?

Comment: The random aspect is which of the predefined statements is selected. For example I could have 10 statements and when I create a new job entry, one of these is picked at random and saved in the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm following and it sounds like the job for a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) with a custom [field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types).

In your example, since you want to use a [Dropdown](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/dropdown-fields) field, then your plugin's field type could extend Craft's default Dropdown field type.

When populating the field type's default values (from your pre-defined statements), you could then randomly select which ones are selected on new entries).

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll dig into it, about time I understood more about writing plugins.